# Adding RadioButtons to ContextMenu

Tags: java, android, menu, contextmenu

I would like to add radio buttons to my context menu, but I'm not sure how. This is how it is created:

```
@Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Selection Options");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove");  
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

from your code:

```
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove");
```

v is a View that can be a RadioButton or any other type of Views.

if you are not using xml to define RadioButton. you should set its ID in your application.

v.setId();

Or you can define ids.xml in res/values.

samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/RadioGroup1.java samples/ApiDemp/res/values/ids.xml

Menu & Context Menu developers guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

if you scroll the above page you can find RadioButton sample in context menu.

Quote form the above page:

> Checkable menu items
>
> A menu can be useful as an interface
>   for turning options on and off, using
>   a checkbox for stand-alone options, or
>   radio buttons for groups of mutually
>   exclusive options. Figure 2 shows a
>   submenu with items that are checkable
>   with radio buttons.
>
> Note: Menu items in the Icon Menu
>   (from the Options Menu) cannot display
>   a checkbox or radio button. If you
>   choose to make items in the Icon Menu
>   checkable, you must manually indicate
>   the checked state by swapping the icon
>   and/or text each time the state
>   changes.
>
> You can define the checkable behavior
>   for individual menu items using the
>   android:checkable attribute in the
>    element, or for an entire group
>   with the android:checkableBehavior
>   attribute in the  element. For
>   example, all items in this menu group
>   are checkable with a radio button:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <menu
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
>         <item android:id="@+id/red"
>               android:title="@string/red" />
>         <item android:id="@+id/blue"
>               android:title="@string/blue" />
>     </group> </menu> The android:checkableBehavior attribute
```

> accepts either:
>
> single Only one item from the group
>   can be checked (radio buttons) all All
>   items can be checked (checkboxes) none
>   No items are checkable You can apply a
>   default checked state to an item using
>   the android:checked attribute in the
>    element and change it in code
>   with the setChecked() method.
>
> When a checkable item is selected, the
>   system calls your respective
>   item-selected callback method (such as
>   onOptionsItemSelected()). It is here
>   that you must set the state of the
>   checkbox, because a checkbox or radio
>   button does not change its state
>   automatically. You can query the
>   current state of the item (as it was
>   before the user selected it) with
>   isChecked() and then set the checked
>   state with setChecked(). For example:

```
> @Override public boolean
> onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
> switch (item.getItemId()) {   case
> R.id.vibrate:   case
> R.id.dont_vibrate:
>     if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
>     else item.setChecked(true);
>     return true;   default:
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   }
> }
```

If you don't set the checked state

> this way, then the visible state of
>   the item (the checkbox or radio
>   button) will not change when the user
>   selects it. When you do set the state,
>   the Activity preserves the checked
>   state of the item so that when the
>   user opens the menu later, the checked
>   state that you set is visible.
>
> Note: Checkable menu items are
>   intended to be used only on a
>   per-session basis and not saved after
>   the application is destroyed. If you
>   have application settings that you
>   would like to save for the user, you
>   should store the data using Shared
>   Preferences.

Comment: I am not inflating my context menu from XML. how can I do it in code?

Comment: not sure if i get what you mean. what would I set for v.setId()?

Comment: in order to add a View (RadioButton here) to a Menu you have to add method in menu. (manu.add(...))  the second parameter in this method is your view id (RadioButton id). if you created your RadioButton by code, you need to set its id by code too. but if you are loading it from xml then its id already assigned.

Answer (score -1):

```
RadioButton rBtn1 = new RadioButton(this);
RadioButton rBtn2 = new RadioButton(this);
rBtn1.setText("radio button 1");
rBtn2.setText("radio button 2");
//Add all your RadioButtons the same way.

RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this);
group.addView(rBtn1);
group.addView(rBtn2);

menu.add(0, group.getId(), 0, "whatever");
```

I didn't try it but I hope it works: